# Can we keep under dynamic variable reference to some method to Invoke it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to create some `UserControl` and implement this code

```
public dynamic CommandContext { set; get; }
```

in order to keep there some **reference to method & parameters** I need to execute.
(If it is possible)

So at the same class of the `UserControl` I have got

#region Apply Command

```
    private ICommand _applyCommand;

    public ICommand ApplyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_applyCommand == null)
            {
                _applyCommand = new RelayCommand(ApplyObject,  CanApply);
            }
            return _applyCommand;
        }
    }

    private void ApplyObject()
    {
        // use CommandContext and execute method od the ANY CLASS It has
    }

    private bool CanApply()
    {
        bool result = true;
        // Verify command can be executed here
        return result;
    }

    #endregion
```

So I am wondering if somehow I can INVOKE this method directly like

```
private void ApplyObject()
{
      CommandContext.CloseWindow();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is **extremely** unclear.

Comment: @SLaks Yes. I know. Hahaha... I need some CONTAINER to keep any reference to any object I need so it should be possible to execute it under `ApplyObject()`...

Comment: @SLaks In general I need to call some methods of the `MainWindow` in the  some `UserControl`, but that `UserControl`shouldn't have code to decide which method to call but just call this method. Because I will use this `UserControl` in different places of the application and I have to pass it different methods. I am not sure how to resolve this  task...

Comment: Number one the UI is not the right place for that. Number two you should be using `Action<T>` in any case, or some kind of `EventAggregator`.

Comment: @HighCore Thank you! I will read around it. The first solution I am working around is to try to use `internal static MyApp.MainWindow _me;` field in child `UserControl`... But here ` private void ApplyObject()
        {
             MainWindow._me.DoSomething(); // ???
        }`  I am getting stuck because I have to hard-code the method name what I don't like to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make it clear:

You should be using [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) or  [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) for that:

```
public class SomeClassThatCallsAnAction
{
    public Action SomeAction {get;set;}

    private void CallTheAction()
    {
        if (SomeAction != null)
           SomeAction();
    }
}

public class ClassThatDefinesTheAction:
{
    private SomeClassThatCallsAnAction instance;

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
          instance = new SomeClassThatCallsAnAction();
          instance.SomeAction = ThisIsTheAction;
    }

    private void ThisIsTheAction()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Action Executed!!);
    }
}
```

Explanation:

the `ThisIsTheAction()` method is assigned to the `SomeAction` property of the `instance`.
Then, when the `instance` calls the `SomeAction()` Action (which holds a reference to the `ThisIsTheAction()` method, that method is executed.

Note:

**The UI is probably not the right place for this**.

Create proper ViewModels to define your application logic.